# Apollo MockedProvider not returning expected data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I wrote a hook that calls apollo `useQuery`. It's pretty simple:

useDecider:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const GET_DECIDER = gql`
  query GetDecider($name: [String]!) {
    deciders(names: $name) {
      decision
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

export const useDecider = name => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);

  useQuery(GET_DECIDER, {
    variables: {
      name
    },
    onCompleted: data => {
      const decision = data?.deciders[0]?.decision;
      setEnabled(decision);
    },

    onError: error => {
      return error;
    }
  });

  return {
    enabled
  };
};
```

I'm trying to test it now and the `MockedProvider` is not returning the expected data:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { useDecider, GET_DECIDER } from './useDecider';

const getMock = (value = false, decider = '') => [
  {
    request: {
      query: GET_DECIDER,
      variables: {
        name: decider
      }
    },
    result: () => {
      console.log('APOLLO RESULT');

      return {
        data: {
          deciders: [
            {
              decision: value,
              name: decider,
              value: 10
            }
          ]
        }
      };
    }
  }
];

const FakeComponent = ({ decider }) => {
  const { enabled } = useDecider(decider);
  return <div>{enabled ? 'isEnabled' : 'isDisabled'}</div>;
};

const WrappedComponent = ({ decider, value }) => (
  <MockedProvider mocks={getMock(value, decider)} addTypename={false}>
    <FakeComponent decider={decider} />
  </MockedProvider>
);

describe('useDecider', () => {
  it('when decider returns true', () => {
    // should return true
    render(<WrappedComponent decider="fake_decider" value={true} />);
    screen.debug();
    const result = screen.getByText('isEnabled');
    expect(result).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about what the `MockedProvider` is returning?  Or perhaps a codesandbox?

Comment: MockedProvider is an export from @apollo: `import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';`  I'm trying to follow docs https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/

Comment: I meant, what data is the `MockedProvider` returning in your test?  You said the data was not what was expected.

Comment: Nothing, `data = undefined`. I added `console.log(loading, data) and `loading = true` but i never see it switch to `false`

Comment: I strongly recommend using `jest.mockImplementation()` for mocking Apollo queries' responses. `MockedProvider` works in a very mysterious way

Answer (score 5):

From https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/#testing-the-success-state

> To test how your component is rendered after its query completes, you
> can await a zero-millisecond timeout before performing your checks.
> This delays the checks until the next "tick" of the event loop, which
> gives MockedProvider an opportunity to populate the mocked result

try adding before your expect call

```
  await act(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I simplified your hook implementation and put together a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-paper-0ommb?file=/src/useDecider.js:0-369):

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_DECIDER = gql`
  query GetDecider($name: [String]!) {
    deciders(names: $name) {
      decision
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

export const useDecider = (name) => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_DECIDER, { variables: { name } });
  return { enabled: data?.deciders[0]?.decision || false };
};
```

Note that in the test I also updated your `getBy` to an `await findBy`:

```
describe("useDecider", () => {
  it("when decider returns true", async () => {
    // should return true
    render(<WrappedComponent decider="fake_decider" value={true} />);
    screen.debug();
    const result = await screen.findByText("isEnabled");
    expect(result).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

This is because you need to wait for your API call to complete before the data will be on the page, hence you would not expect the data to be there on the first render.

[image]

Comment: Tried your implementation but the test is failing

Comment: Did you update the test?  The code is working on the link I posted.

Comment: if you console out the result from the test, it's not correct. Not sure why the test is passing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I logged the result and got <div>isEnabled</div>.  Am I missing something?  Could you update the sandbox to show what isn't working?

Comment: After a restart it works in codesandbox, but I copied exactly the same test and updates to useDecider to local and it fails for some reason

Comment: Can't do much more without new information.  Let me know.

Comment: Yea there's an open issue https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6803

I had to use spyOn useQuery